# Failed to Call Graph API /beta/me/joinedTeams

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

This Graph API failed for some of our accounts since yesterday, could you advise a fix?
P.S. Those users could sign in Microsoft Teams and see all associated teams.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams

Below is the error message from Graph Explorer:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": "GeneralException",
  "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "79bc9855-8181-4f65-811e-780c5bcf0a53",
    "date": "2018-05-11T06:44:27"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. Without seeing some sample code or more details on how you're calling, there isn't a lot for the community go on.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur There's no code required, the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) provide the robust web UI to verify it, just sign in and paste the endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams, then run it.

Answer (score 0):

That appears Microsoft already fixed this, so let's close it.